# Problems Building MPFR using iOS SDK 8.3

Tags: ios, build, arm, configure, mpfr

I am having trouble building MPFR for iOS, armv7s architecture. I am using this command after successfully building GMP,

```
./configure CC=clang CPP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -arch armv7s -target arm-apple-darwin" --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
```

However, I configure is giving me the error

> libgmp not found or uses a different ABI.

I built GMP with the same configure settings as above, then make, make install, etc. After this, I copied the gmp.h file and libgmp.la file to

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/

and

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib

respectively, but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think being tired got to me, and I was using an x86_64 version of GMP to try to compile the armv7 mpfr. I retried today, and everything worked. Make sure to move the gmp header and the libgmp.a file to the iOS sdk directories as mentioned in the question, else you will get an error at configure time. Other than that, it should work.